# VBA copy range of rows

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to copy range of rows and paste those into other sheet?
I've tried this but i get 1004 error:

```
.Rows(i_cls_frst_row, i_cls_last_row).Copy
```

Regards
Michał

Comment: You'll need to post more of the code.  It's impossible to tell where the error is coming from with only one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

If you have non contiguous rows like `i_cls_frst_row=1` and `i_cls_last_row=3` and you are trying to copy two rows then try this

```
Range(i_cls_frst_row & ":" & i_cls_frst_row & "," & _
      i_cls_last_row & ":" & i_cls_last_row).Copy
```

If you are trying to copy from `i_cls_frst_row` to `i_cls_last_row` then try this

```
Rows(i_cls_frst_row & ":" & i_cls_last_row).Copy
```

Comment: first time ever typing faster than you :)

Comment: True... But I was covering both scenarios ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, change your line

```
.Rows(i_cls_frst_row, i_cls_last_row).Copy
```

to:

```
.Rows(i_cls_frst_row & ":" & i_cls_last_row).Copy
```

Then later on you can paste it where you need

Answer (score 1):

Use a range of rows:

```
Range(Rows(i_cls_frst_row), Rows(i_cls_last_row)).Copy
```

Or a Range's EntireRow property:

```
Range(Cells(i_cls_frst_row, 1), Cells(i_cls_last_row, 1)).EntireRow.Copy
```

You can also use a Range Resize, if you know the number or rows you wish to copy:

```
Rows(i_cls_frst_row).Resize(2).copy
(this copies 2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Range object and select all the required rows/row as a Range

```
Dim example As Range
Set example = Range("A1:E1")
example.Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: That is so old that I dont remember if I've tested your solution and for some reason it didn't work. siddhart provided proper answer and let's stick to that.